# Sparse Voxel Octrees which parts on GPU or CPU?

Tags: architecture, algorithm, voxels, gpu, octree

I'm currently doing research into building my own voxel engine and found a lot of articles mentioning SVOs as the best mechanism. I just wanted to know that I understood the algorithm correctly, before I implement it.

I read my data into an octree on the CPU, maintained through standard node->children constructs. With that I can do collision detection, frustum culling, etc.

For rendering the octree is then written to a texture and processed by vertex and pixel shader to display the actual voxel directly on the GPU. Although I guess I could walk the octree on the CPU, and instead of building the texture, draw the individual voxels through instancing although probably a bit slower.

Is that correct or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyril Crassin just published his thesis on Gigavoxels: http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2011/Cra11/

I'm sure it's going to answer lots of your questions.

Sorry for not being able to help you myself, I thought pointing you to this reference would be useful though.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very good in-depth resource. I'll leave the question open for a bit though, maybe someone else can answer it more directly.

Answer (score 0):

More recent work by Laine (Nvidia) and source code here: http://research.nvidia.com/publication/efficient-sparse-voxel-octrees-analysis-extensions-and-implementation